# Image as db.Blob() not showing from the DataStore

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2

in my Google AppEngine project I'm trying to save details on a Movie, including an image, and then show the image on my main page but the image is just not showing. I'm using Python and Jinja2. Does anyone know why?

```
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os
import datetime
import time
import cgi
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.api import images

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class Movie(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    release_date = db.StringProperty()
    duration = db.StringProperty()
    director = db.StringProperty()
    actors = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    summary = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    picture = db.BlobProperty()
    trailer = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Image(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    movie = db.get(self.request.get('img_id'))
    if movie.picture:
        img = images.Image(movie.picture)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
        self.response.out.write(img)
    else:
        self.response.out.write("No Image")

class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    movies = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                        "FROM Movie "
                        "ORDER BY release_date DESC LIMIT 5")
    template_values = { 'movies': movies}                                   
    template = jinja_environment.get_template('home_page.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

class Admin(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    template_values = {}
    template = jinja_environment.get_template('admin.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))


def post(self):
    name = self.request.get('name')
    release_date = self.request.get('release_date')
    c = time.strptime(release_date,"%m/%d/%Y")
    release_date = time.strftime("%m%d%Y",c)
    duration = self.request.get('duration')
    director = self.request.get('director')
    actors = self.request.get('actors')
    summary = self.request.get('summary')
    picture = self.request.get('img')
    trailer = self.request.get('trailer')

    movie = Movie(key_name = name)
    movie.release_date = release_date
    movie.duration = duration
    movie.director = director
    movie.actors = actors
    movie.summary = summary
    movie.picture = db.Blob(str(picture))
    movie.trailer = trailer
    movie.put()
    self.redirect('/')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/admin', Admin), ('/', Main)], debug=True)
```

And this is the HTML of home_page.html:

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        <th>Top Movies</th>

        {% for movie in movies %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{movie.key().name() }} &nbsp</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href = "/movie_data?movie_key = {{movie.key() }}"> <img src = "img?img_id={{movie.key()}}"> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp </td>


        </tr>

        {% endfor %}

        <a href = "/admin">admin</a>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the admin.html:

```
html>
<body dir="ltr">
    <form action="/admin" method="post"> 
    <table>

        <th colspan="2"><h1>Add New Movie</h1><br/></th>

        <tr><td>Movie Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name"/><br/></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Release Date (MM/DD/YYYY):</td><td><input type="text" name="release_date" /><br/></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Duration (minutes):</td><td><input type="text" name="duration" /><br/></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Director:</td><td><input type="text" name="director" /><br/></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Main Actors:</td><td><textarea name="actors" rows = "5" cols = "20"></textarea><br/></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Summary:</td><td><textarea name="summary" rows = "5" cols = "20"></textarea><br/></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Upload Picture</td><td><input type="file" name="img"/><br/></td></tr>

        <tr><td>Trailer Code:</td><td><textarea name="trailer" rows = "5" cols = "20"></textarea><br/></td></tr>



        <tr><td><br/><input type="submit" /> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <input type="reset" /></td></tr>

    </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no handler that routes to Image

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/admin', Admin), ('/', Main),('/img', Image)], debug=True)
```

Comment: And he needs to build that handler

Comment: Thanks! the routing was missing (the handler exists I have an Image Class)..but it still doesn't work...Do you have any other suggestions maybe?

Comment: add enctype="multipart/form-data" to the form tag